# Elixir/Ecto: Why is ^pin operator needed here?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm watching an Elixir Sip screencast, and he puts a pin on the `where` clause.

I'm trying to figure out why that is, as I thought it's only used on the left hand side of a pattern match.

(Sorry for the image, its a video)

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484790/why-are-pin-operators-necessary-in-ecto-queries